# Как сделать систему "поднятия" пользовательских записей?

Tags: php, mysql

Цель: сделать систему "поднятий" как к примеру, на avito, ну то есть человек платит n-ую сумму денег и его запись становиться первой в выдаче, и далее по мере добавления новых записей его запись опускаться ниже в выдаче.

Comment: `ORDER BY` по любому вашему полю в таблице, а это поле заполняйте как вам угодно

Comment: `ORDER BY IS_PAID DESC, DATETIME_PAID DESC, ID DESC`

Comment: Сортируйте записи например по дате. И когда нужно поднять, просто меняйте дату на текущую, и запись станет первой